# Ubuntu 22.04.1 autoinstall cloud-config fails

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init, ubuntu-22.04

I'm currently having an issue installing Ubuntu 22.04 via cloud-init.
The server has two hard drives. There should be a /data partition on the second hard disk, but currently, the installation doesn't work.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsvR.jpg)
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the storage configuration?

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  users:
  - default
  - name: ubuntu
    passwd: "$6$rmFIz9Pdwb1$jsUGBTC46WkdnwLos4/6TqNnZaEdR7mV/XFfcvsnQXNKqgt.oZ2HTvboeZNP/qcNQXQqKkKnAU5i0Dh4GeAwA0"
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock-passwd: false
    ssh_pwauth: True
    chpasswd: { expire: False }
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu2204
    username: ubuntu
    password: "$6$rmFIz9Pdwb1$jsUGBTC46WkdnwLos4/6TqNnZaEdR7mV/XFfcvsnQXNKqgt.oZ2HTvboeZNP/qcNQXQqKkKnAU5i0Dh4GeAwA0"
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    install-server: true
  user-data:
    disable_root: false
    timezone: Europe/Berlin
  locale: de_DE
  keyboard:
    layout: de
  storage:
    config:
      - type: disk
        id: disk0
        grub_device: true
        wipe: superblock
        path: /dev/sda
        ptable: gpt
        match:
          size: largest
      - type: disk
        id: disk1
        path: /dev/sdb
        ptable: gpt
        match:
         size: smallest
      - type: partition
        id: boot-partition
        flag: boot
        device: disk0
        size: 500M
        number: 1
      - type: partition
        id: root-partition
        device: disk0
        number: 2
        size: -1
        wipe: superblock
      - type: partition
        id: data-partition
        number: 1
        device: disk1
        size: -1
      - id: boot-partition-fs
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        volume: boot-partition
      - id: root-partition-fs
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        volume: root-partition
      - id: data-partition-fs
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        volume: data-partition
      - id: boot-partition-fs-mount
        type: mount
        path: /boot
        device: boot-partition-fs
      - id: root-partition-fs-mount
        type: mount
        path: /
        device: root-partition-fs
      - id: data-partition-fs-mount
        type: mount
        path: /data
        device: data-partition-fs
  late-commands:
    - echo 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
```

Comment: have you checked /var/crash ?